# Kill both commands that run simultaneously in bash

Tags: shell, background-process, signals, process-management

I want to run two commands simultaneously in bash script (one of them is another bash script) and I need both of them to stop when I press Ctrl+C.
My bash script now is:

```
#!/bin/bash

./command1 &

exec "/path/to/bash2"
```

and in bash2:

```
#!/bin/bash

[..]
python run.py
```

Should I add a trap to kill both commands?
If so, adding the following in bash did not help

```
trap killgroup SIGINT

killgroup(){
  echo killing...
  kill 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to ensure you're `kill`-ing the correct PID:

```
./command1 &
childpid=$!
trap "kill -TERM ${childpid}" EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel respects ctrl-c. So you can run:

```
parallel ::: ./command1 /path/to/bash2
```